# Beta decay of 6-Helium

Tags: nuclear-physics

In this reaction:

$$\require{mhchem}
\ce{^6_2He ->{^6_3Li}}$$

in the initial state there are two neutrons in the $1p_{3/2}$ that coupled (for the Pauli's principle) with antiparallel spin, so $J_i=0$, when the He decay the neutron transform in proton that occupy the same state but with parallel spin, so $J_f=1$. This reaction has $\Delta J=1$ so is a Gamow-Teller decay (allowed).

Why the transformed proton can't occupy the same state but antiparallel so the $J_f=0$?

Comment: So you want the spin to flip? Why?

Comment: no, Im trying to understand why the proton occupies the same level with spin parallel to the neutron and not the opposite. Is it due to greater stability when coupled in parallel?